# Scroller object not working in IE7 But Working in IE8

Tags: javascript, dom-events, runtime-error, jscrollpane

I am having difficulties trying to solve a runtime error that I get in IE7 but its working fine in IE8, it says that `this.scroller` is null or not an object for a scroller that I use, but what surprises me is that it is working on every browser. Please I need a solution. If I have not clarified my question please let me know. I am just looking for a reason that may cause this.

Comment: Could you please put a code snippet to explain the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried checking pulling back scroller using getElementsbyID instead?

```
var elem = document.getElementById("scroller");
if (!elem)
{
   //do stuff
}
```